# The solution is executed with error 'out of bounds' on the line 12

Tags: c++

I dont see any bugs in this code,can anyone find it out for me?It says that the solution is executed because the array team[n] is out of bounds when the value n=60 is given.
here is the half of the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

int n;    
cin>>n;
int i,cnt=0,participate=0,f=1;
int *team=new int[n];
int *arr =new int[n];
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cin>>team[i];
    cout<<team[i]<<" ";
    arr[i] = team[i];
}
cout<<"\n"<<i;}
```

This code is written using c++.Thanks!

Comment: `i = 0; i<n; ++i` c++ is [0-based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

Comment: @Ch3steR why ++i? what if i write i=0;i<n;i++ ?

Comment: @AfifAl'Hasnain In this case it makes no difference, but in general case prefix increment can be faster (on more complex types than int)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the arrays uses 0-based indexing it means for n elements in the array the indexing is from **0 to n-1** and hence you get the out of bounds error. You should change your for loop to something like-

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    // do somthing here ...
}
```

Note: For element up to n in array you should initialize array as `new temp[n+1]` but again it will have n+1 elements inside it and indexing will be from 0 to n.